# How to set default roll on a-frame 350 video?

Tags: video, aframe

```
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" >

    <a-assets>
        <video id="video" src="video-360.mp4" autoplay="false" loop crossorigin></video>
    </a-assets>


    <a-videosphere src="#video"position="-4 0 0"></a-videosphere> // tried rotation="-40 0 0"

</a-scene>
```

Hi guys, i am working on a 360 video project, aframe fits my need but with the above code the video starts playing the video from right side, i have to pan it manually to view the video. is it possible to set the default camera angle so the camera is facing at the middle of the video rather than right.

i tried position and rotation attributes, but position seems to have no effect, and rotation doesn't roll the camera to the left.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually do not want to specify the rotation of the camera since it will be modified by the user when he or she will move his or her head. Consequently try instead to apply the rotation to the object or the world around the user instead. So despite your description applying the rotation to the videosphere is correct, just try `rotation="0 -40 0"` instead. Also consider using the [inspector](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/guides/using-the-aframe-inspector.html#using-the-inspector) if you want to conveniently find the right value.

PS: the video sphere is a very large sphere (radius of `5000`) so modifying it's position will have nearly no effect.

Comment: thanks @Utopiah , `rotation="0 -80 0"` worked for me, thanks for the tip